# Dictionary with sorted unique values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm facing the following problem. I have the following dict with unique keys and multiple values:

```
dic = {'Hipster': ['John', 'Thomas','Peter'],'Geek': ['Irvin'], 'Funny': 
['Lucas','Thomas'],'Clever': ['Peter']}
```

I want to create a new dictionary such as: i) It starts with the key which has the highest number of values, ii) The values associated to the keys are unique ie. They are not associated to a previous key. The output would be:

```
dic2 = {'Hipster': ['John', 'Thomas','Peter'],'Geek': ['Irvin'],'Funny': 
['Lucas']}
```

More formally, it is like transforming the following dictionary:

```
Initial_dic = {key1:[Values1],key2:[Values2],key3:[Values3],....]
Final_dic = {key1:[Values1],key2:[Values2-Values1],key3:[Value3-Values2-Values1],....]
```

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service; show us what you've tried.

Comment: The keys in a dictionary are unordered. They can't start with a certain key.

Comment: @interjay You can order your dictionary for instance by using collections import OrderedDict. You'll get a dictionary type object.

Comment: @l'L'l If I ask it's because have been struggling on it for hours and because I think other people could benefit from it. Having a dictionary sorted to get the importance of each keys and unique values associated to them looks pretty general no ?

Comment: @Jb_Eyd: sorting by length is easy (`sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[-1]), reverse=True)`), but you have an additional requirement that isn't clear.

Comment: @Jb_Eyd: Not showing the code you've been struggling with doesn't benefit anyone though. If anything it helps illustrate what you need to fix while at the same time showing you made an attempt at it.

Comment: @Jb_Eyd: does order matter in the lists? E.g. is it fine to return `['Peter', 'Thomas']` where the original input list was `['Thomas', 'Peter']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this in two passes; sort and discard values:

```
def order_and_strip(d):
    sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[-1]), reverse=True)
    seen = set()
    for key, value in sorted_items:
        yield key, list(set(value) - seen)
        seen.update(value)
```

I'm assuming here that order in the output lists is not important. If it is, use a list comprehension:

```
yield key, [v for v in value if v not in seen]
```

The above is a generator that yields key-value pairs in sorted order. You could put these into an `OrderedDict()` if you want to treat this as a dictionary with a specific key order:

```
result = OrderedDict(order_and_strip(dic))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all dictionaries have no distinct order.
you should think about a more approprate data structure for your Problem. 
If you want to stick on dict's you at least should use a OrderedDict 
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

None the less you could try this:

```
import collections

input_dic = {'Hipster': ['John', 'Thomas','Peter'],'Geek': ['Irvin'], 'Funny': 
['Lucas','Thomas'],'Clever': ['Peter']}



def do_courious_dict_action(dic):
    o_dic = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.iteritems(),key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True))
    tmp_dic = {}
    for item in o_dic.iteritems():  
        temp_list = item[1] 
        for i in range(0,o_dic.keys().index(item[0])):
            temp_list = [x for x in temp_list if x not in o_dic.items()[i][1]]
        tmp_dic[item[0]] = temp_list



    tmp2_dic = {k:v for k, v in tmp_dic.iteritems() if len(v)>0}

    new_o_dic = collections.OrderedDict()

    for ordered_key in o_dic.keys():
        if ordered_key in tmp2_dic:
            new_o_dic[ordered_key] = tmp2_dic[ordered_key]

    return new_o_dic

print do_courious_dict_action(input_dic)
```

It does almost produce what you want, exept it switches 'Funny' and 'Geek', since funny had 2 entries at the beginning. But maybe it gives you a hint in which direction you should look into

Edit:
Okay the Solution of Martijn Pieters with generators is much more pythonic ;-)